# Inner join em procedure

Tags: banco-de-dados, sql-server

Estou criando um pequeno banco de dados no SQL Server, para um projeto em ASP.NET mvc de meu curso.

Usando ADO.NET estou criando procedures, para utilizar na minha classe DAL, até ai tudo bem tem muita informação sobre e tudo mais, no entanto, oque eu preciso fazer é realizar um join dentro de uma procedure, não achei nada sobre ou pelo menos nada que eu tenha entendido como funciona.

O problema é que não estou entendendo como devo colocar os parâmetros das duas tabelas na minha procedure para realizar o select com inner join.

Tentei desta forma:

```html
CREATE TABLE PRODUTO(
ID_PRATO INTEGER PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
FK_CATEGORIA_ID INT,
DESCRICAO_PRATO VARCHAR(200),
VALOR DECIMAL(5,2) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT FK_CATEGORIA_ID FOREIGN KEY (FK_CATEGORIA_ID) REFERENCES CATEGORIA (ID_CATEGORIA)
)
GO

CREATE TABLE ENTREGA(
ID_ENTREGA INTEGER PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
FK_PRATO_ID2 INT,
CONSTRAINT FK_PRATO_ID2 FOREIGN KEY (FK_PRATO_ID2) REFERENCES PRODUTO (ID_PRATO),
STATUS_ENTREGA VARCHAR(10) CHECK (STATUS_ENTREGA IN ('CANCELADA','TRANSITO','REALIZADA'))
)
GO


create procedure sp_select_produto
(
  @id_prato int,
 @descricao_cat varchar(200),
 @descricao_prato varchar(200),
 @valor decimal(5,2)
) 
as
select prod.id_prato,cat.descricao_cat,prod.descricao_prato,prod.valor from CATEGORIA 
as cat inner join PRODUTO prod 
on cat.id_categoria=prod.FK_CATEGORIA_ID
where prod.id_prato=ID_PRATO
return
```

Mas quando dou um exec um erro aparece:

```
Mensagem 201, Nível 16, Estado 4, Procedimento sp_select_produto, Linha 225 O procedimento ou a função 'sp_select_produto' espera o parâmetro '@id_prato', que não foi fornecido.
```

Alguma ideia de como posso fazer nesse caso ?

Comment: Simplesmente na sua chamada da `procedure` (que você não mostrou na sua pergunta) não existe uma passagem para o parâmetro `id_prato`.

Comment: No momento, não estou realizando a chamada no projeto estava tentando testar dentro do sql server manager somente, mas entendi o que disse irei realizar mais testes obrigado

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A mensagem:

> ```
> Mensagem 201, Nível 16, Estado 4, Procedimento sp_select_produto, Linha 225 O procedimento ou a função 'sp_select_produto' espera o parâmetro '@id_prato', que não foi fornecido.
> ```

Indica que o parâmetro `@id_prato` foi adicionado na declaração da sua `procedure` porém não foi adicionado na chamada da mesma. Para executar a `procedure` você deve passar todos os parâmetros que são obrigatório:

```
EXEC sp_procedure @parametro1, @parametro2
```

Ou, se o parâmetro não for obrigatório, adicione um valor padrão na declaração:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_procedure @parametro_obrigatorio INTEGER, @parametro_opcional INTEGER = NULL AS
-- ...
```

E realize a chamada com parâmetros nomeados:

```
EXEC sp_procedure @parametro_obrigatorio = 1
```

Comment: Entendi, o where que eu coloquei precisa ter o @id_prato preenchido no momento da execução para que eu possa executar a procedure

Comment: @NelsonFrancisco então realmente é só adicionar o parâmetro na chamada que o erro irá sumir

Comment: Acabei de testar deu tudo certo obrigado mesmo ..